# Gradle: how to define a task that is execute prior to my tasks of type Test

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

besides the typical `test { ... }` I have multiple test 'scenarios' defined such as

```
test 111(type: Test) { ... }
test 222(type: Test) { ... }
test 333(type: Test) { ... }
```

All 4 scenarios (including `test { ... }`) require some common config code. Is it possible to configure a new task, e.g. `testConfig { task -> ... }` that is used irrespective which test task I invoke, **without** adding the dependency explicitly to every Test task. May be something like `Test.doFirst{ task -> testConfig task }`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks need to be configured in the *configuration phase*, before any task has been executed. Commonalities can be configured using *configuration rules*. For example:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    forkEvery = 50
    jvmArgs "-Xmx1024m"
    ...
}

task test111(type: Test) { ... }
task test222(type: Test) { ... }
task test333(type: Test) { ... }
```